# Skype Starts Dialing and Hangs Up After 2 Seconds - Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, skype

I have `Skype` (`2.8.0.920`) installed on two `Android` devices. The first device comes with Android 2.2, second with 4.04.

when I initiate a call by executing the following code...

```
Intent skype_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"); 
skype_intent.setClassName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main");   
skype_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                  
skype_intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:PassportCard"));                 
act.startActivity(skype_intent);
```

...Skype starts dialing *and* hangs up after 2 sec.

However, the code works fine if I replace the current (`2.8.0.920`) Skype version by the *previous*.

Why is this? Any help?

Comment: Maybe some bug in Skype itself!

Comment: can u tell me what was ur previous version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found ;

```
In Java file:
Intent iskype = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW"); 
iskype.setData(Uri.parse("skype:PassportCard")); 
act.startActivity(iskype);

In AndroidManifast.xml
<intent-filter> 
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />                     
      <data android:scheme="skype" /> 
</intent-filter>
```